# QuickMapServices does not work in QGIS 3.24 Tisler as worked before?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, upgrade

I was working with the Google satellite basemap from QuickMapServices using the projected coordinate system NAD83(2011)/UTM zone 15N, and everything was working fine, but today after the upgrade of QGIS the basemap is not displaying as it was before.

I understand that the original CRS of this basemap is WGS84, but why was it working before and not now? Is there any solution besides reprojecting my data to WGS84 (I need a CRS working on meters, and I have more than 1000 files in .las format that I don't want to reproject)?

*EDIT*: When I say it is not displaying as before, I meant that it appears in the wrong place, like if the data and the basemap were on different planets. Or just doesn't appear anywhere.

*EDIT 2*: I am adding a screenshot that may be useful, it shows the project properties. First, when I try to select the CRS that I want for my project (EPSG:6344 - NAD83(2011)/UTM zone 15N) is like QGIS doesn't know where the projection should be used. Here is the description of this CRS, and before the upgrade, this was shown in the image below https://epsg.io/6344.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you shared more information - what do you mean by 'not displaying as it was before'. Is nothing showing up, or is it showing up in the wrong place, or is it distorted? If you could share a screenshot of what you're seeing that would help.

Comment: Hi @she_weeds I added the answer to your question, I did not post the screenshots because they are just whiteboards because the basemap is not displaying on the screen today.

Comment: Did you just open an old project with the new version or did you add the base map in a new project ? Id you opened an old one try to reset the basemap projection ( it probably not straight wgs84 but rather web mercator)

Comment: Both. I used to use the basemap in an old project, and after the upgrade, the basemap disappeared from that project (it wasn't visible in my study area). Now, when I created a new project with the projected system that I need, it shows but in the wrong place compared to my data, this is what I mean by a different planet. When I hover my mouse over the data I see coordinates in NAD83(2011)/UTM zone 15N, when I do it over the basemap the coordinates are in WGS84.

Comment: Did you touch the basemap's CRS at all? Don't! It should probably be EPSG:3857 and QMS does that correctly. I have no issues looking at a Google map loaded with QMS and the project CRS set to 6344 here if I zoom in onto the USA enough.

Comment: Actually, it looks like EPSG:6344 is broken in your QGIS installation. Mine looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVfc1.png . What is your Proj version (listed in the About screen)?

Comment: No, I didn't change the basemap's CRS (never had to do it before with other QGIS versions). My PROJ version is 6.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fix my problem.

1. I uninstalled Qgis using the instructions given here [Uninstall Qgis](https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-focal-fossa/package/qgis)
2. Then, I tried to install it again using the [official instructions from Qgis](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) this give me the error

   `The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

   `qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: grass782`

   `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
3. Therefore, I could not use the qgis-plugin-grass, this apparently controls the functions that I was trying to use (not sure how, or why). Finally, after many tries, I find this [issue in the Qgis github repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38329), they explain in more detail why to change this line in the installation `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"` by this one `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis $(lsb_release -c -s) main"`

so, in conclusion, uninstall and then install but with the ubuntugis repository.